# apple paid developer program ban or not when i use Mac OS in VMWare?

Tags: ios, macos, vmware

I am using Windows operating system where i use VMWare for running MacOS. Is there any obstacle or ban my apple developer ID (paid $99) when i distribute my app in app store?

Comment: Long story short.. **NO**.   Make sure your app won't violate these rules https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a TOS legal consulting firm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Apple has bigger things to care about.

If you had violated the EULA on iCloud or ItunesConnect why not but using a hackintosh is not a violation for iCloud or you are apple ID. There is now a way for them to prevent you from using the operating system without legal action.

However, using a hackintosh is in violation with apples’ EULA which you must agree to in order to have their software licensed to you. In the EULA it states that the OS (macOS) must be installed on apple branded hardware only so by using a hackintosh, you’re n breach of their EULA. Apple would have the right to take legal action against you for this but in the past this has NEVER been done. Nobody has been prosecuted for installing macOS on non-apple hardware.

Comment: Your first sentence should state "YES, you violate the licence agreement and therefore might be banned etc.". It's a legal thing, which has nothing to do with whether Apple will ever get to know of it or not. If by chance the find out, they might kick you (and your apps) out of everything.

Comment: Even if Apple learns that this person is using an illegal version of Macintosh, his Developer account should not risk much because it is neither the same service nor the same contract.

Comment: Has anyone been kicked out?